# Select rows in dataFrame with the same index using python

Tags: python, pandas, sorting, indexing, pandas-loc

I want to ask you, How to select rows that have the same index number in a DataFrame. Example:

```
df=

  A, B, C,
0 1. 2. 1.
1 2. 2. 2. 
2 2. 2. 2. 
3 3. 3. 4.
  A, B, C,
0 1. 2. 1.
1 2. 2. 2. 
2 2. 2. 0. 
3 3. 3. 4.
  A, B, C,
0 1. 2. 1.
1 2. 2. 2. 
2 0. 2. 2. 
3 3. 3. 4.
```

I expect:

df1=

```
   A, B, C,
 2 2. 2. 2. 
 2 2. 2. 0. 
 2 0. 2. 2.
```

I'm using `df.loc[2]` but only shows me the first set of data. Also used `df1=df.set_index(['2'])` and doesn't works too. Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can't have duplicates in your index.

Comment: can you paste output of df.index and df.columns

Comment: Is wear, my `df.index=
Out[101]: RangeIndex(start=0, stop=874, step=1)` but I can see index of variable length [1,2,3,4,5,,1,2,3,,1,2,3...] and the output of my columns is: `Index(['Unnamed: 0', '0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10',
       '11', '12', '13', '14', '15', '16', '17', '18', '19', '20', '21', '22',
       '23', '24', '25', '26', '27', '28', '29', '30', '31', '32', '33', '34'`

Comment: Can you paste sample input and sample output and the code , what attempts you have made so far at solving the problem?

Answer (score 2):

The index may have duplicates. Especially, when you concatenate different data frames.
Use this to filter data based on your index:

```
df1 = df[df.index==2]
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you need to group by the index values:

```
df1 = df.groupby(df.index).get_group(2)
df1
#   A  B  C
#2  2  2  2
#2  2  2  0
#2  0  2  2
```

Comment: does not work for me! with that I only get the first

Comment: Please update the original question to include the correct definition of `df` (they way it is typed now, it is not a valid Pandas dataframe; I assumed that it had 12 rows, three columns A, B, and C, and a repeated index).